# Why do some addresses show zero transactions even though they had transactions?

Tags: cardano-cli

I'm querying [this address on testnet](https://explorer.cardano-testnet.iohkdev.io/en/address?address=addr_test1qrth9u0url08lh3wyyvs9t5rehuwvmlymechalx3l4ednt37ljw2qfmeg3wrlqzp6zuswfr65gunuugh8mf80naz28msdws93h), which has had two transactions, yet `cardano-cli` shows none:

```
cardano-cli query utxo \
   --testnet-magic 1097911063 \
   --address addr_test1qrth9u0url08lh3wyyvs9t5rehuwvmlymechalx3l4ednt37ljw2qfmeg3wrlqzp6zuswfr65gunuugh8mf80naz28msdws93h

                           TxHash                                 TxIx        Amount
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Why is that?

Comment: Could you have sent the utxo query too soon? Sometimes it takes a second for them to show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're querying UTxOs and not transactions. In order to explore list of transactions you're best off using explorer for [testnet](https://explorer.cardano-testnet.iohkdev.io/en) or [mainnet](https://explorer.cardano.org/en).

If you you need to explore transactions from some app or script either use self-hosted cardano-graphql stack, gimbalabs hosted cardano-graphql and or blockfrost.

Answer (score 1):

You are querying if the specific address contains UTxOs, not past transactions.

`cardano-node` sees only the current state of the blockchain, not historical events. For that, you will need to use `cardano-db-sync` or a hosted alternative such as https://blockfrost.io.

Comment: I don't understand what the difference between the "current state of the blockchain" and "historical events" is. `cardano-node` has access to the full ledger, so it should be able to work out which transactions happened at a given address?